# How to append query string to current url using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Can anybody guide me how to append query string to current url using jquery but it should not get redirected to the new page. I mean it should simply get appended to the current url.
I have tried the following code but it's not working.

```
 $(".package-book a").click(function(){
 window.location.url = "?id=" + $(this).val(<?php the_title(); ?>);
  )};
```

Comment: So you are trying to simply change the value in the address bar of the browser? What exactly are you trying to achieve? There is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: You have an invalid markup `<a>` don't have values.

Comment: I am trying to find jquery code which will append querystring to the current url. This will be used in another jquery code.

Comment: Can the current URL already contain a query string, so you need to merge the new query string with it?

Comment: Can you please show me how???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $(".package-book a").click(function(){
     window.location.url = "?id=" + $(this).val(<?php echo the_title(); ?>);
      )};
```

Either change the code as above or you should echo into your php function `the_title()` whatever you returning in this function.

Comment: hi Nida, the function name the_title() would be giving some return value please remove that return statement and used echo itself inside that function please try and see it.It should work...

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery BBQ (Back Button & Query Library) plugin - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

```
$.bbq.pushState();
```